# How do I pass parameter to set value in SQL Server agent job from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am calling a SQL Server job from a stored procedure like below

```
CREATE PROC StartMyMonthlyInventoryJob
AS
     EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'_TIME_ACCESSABILITY_HOURS'       
GO
```

and I want to change the set values for this job (I know how to configure in graphical way). How do I pass parameters to set value when I call that job from a stored procedure? Thanks

Comment: The only parameter a a sql agent job accepts is the step to begin processing.

Comment: IIRC, you would actually have to alter the job-package definition before starting the job.  That is *very* complicated.  A better practice in general is to write the packages themselves to be able dynamically load their own parameters.  Also complicated, but if you standardize it for all of your packages it becomes no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

Instead you create a table that holds all the parameters that the job would pass to the SSIS package.

Add a new first step to the package to read the parameters from the table and populate the package variables.

Add a new last step to the package to update the parameters-table and either delete the row, or update it with a "completed" flag of some kind.

Comment: I can understand your idea . But any sample query about reading datas from table to step and how to include that step into the JOB. It will be very useful to me . Thanks @Tab Alleman

Comment: I don't have any sample handy, what part of it do you not know how to do?   Can you narrow the focus of your question?

Comment: 1)how to assign data to step    2)how to include step into that job

Comment: 1)   I don't understand what you are asking.   You don't assign data to a step.   2)  You don't add a new step to the job.   You add it to the SSIS package.

Comment: Please close this question by clicking the checkmark icon to the top left of this answer.