# call parameterized SSIS package from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis

I’m using a SP for calling a SSIS package, I was previously using the

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job`.

The problem is that I need to pass a parameter when I’m calling that package and I’m not able to do it. Example below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clawback]
      @Country      CHAR(2)
    , @StartDate        DATETIME
    , @EndDate      DATETIME
AS

BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[ClawbackConfig]
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClawbackConfig] 
(
             Country
            ,StartDate
            ,EndDate
            ) VALUES (
                 @Country
                ,@StartDate
                ,@EndDate
                )

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'ExecuteJob'
```

This Stored Procedure is for running an extract using the desired days and countries, these values are stored in one table and used in the usual incremental process.

I want to mention that the idea is to use the same package for the incremental + clawback and the incremental process needs the country parameter.

So I need somehow to pass the @Country given on this procedure to the package before it runs. 
The package is stored in Integration Services SQL Server 2008 so I’m not able to use the catalog.create_execution or cmd. Any ideas about this? Is the only solution to use C# ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass parameter to set value in SQL Server agent job from stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822332/how-do-i-pass-parameter-to-set-value-in-sql-server-agent-job-from-stored-procedu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it. You can either read from SSIS Configurations (in the called proc see:

```
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/execute-ssis-from-sql/)
```

or you store the values to a table that the invoked proc reads, and  then, uses the read variables in the proc.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Many thanks for the link and the suggestion. I guess I will change the approach and use a configuration table.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct (even if its not what you wanted to hear) you should mark it as acceptable by checking it off. thanks,Ben

Comment: Dead link... got a replacement?